# RegularExpression in MVC 3

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Regular expression for validation in my MVC 3 application.

in my app user need to be able to create folder on ftp. but folder name should only contains numbers,A-Z letters, a-z letters, _.

what ive got now :

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-zåÅøØÆæA-Z-_0-9\s.]+")
```

I **dont** want user to be able to create white spaces after last letter/number in a string.

True value :

```
AsPnG 1.1
```

false value :

```
AsPnG 1.1"space""space"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following expression:

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9\s]*[a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

Comment: do note that the original expression was less strict and allowed a couple of other characters as well, this might or might not have been intentional. Another simple trick to make sure that the last character isn't a space is to use `(?<!\s)$` at the very end of your current expression. it basically ensures your text can never end in a space. Depending on how the Attribute works, you might also want to tag a `^` at the start of the expression to make sure your text doesn't anywhere in its contents have the valid values, but some garbage around it. thus: `^[a-zåÅøØÆæA-Z-_0-9\s.]+(?<!\s)$`